# Example of a formal system that is complete but not strongly complete

Tags: logic

A formal system is *complete* with respect to a semantics, if all validities are derivable (i.e. if $\ \vDash\phi\ $ then $\ \vdash\phi$).

A formal system is *strongly complete* with respect to a semantics, if for every set of formulas $\Gamma$, the formulas that are semantically entailed by $\Gamma$ are derivable from $\Gamma$ (i.e. if $\ \Gamma\vDash\phi\ $ then $\ \Gamma\vdash\phi$).

What is an example of a formal system that is complete wrt a semantics but not strongly complete wrt to that semantics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Segerberg's  Propositional Dynamic Logic (PDL)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-dynamic/) is complete with respect to its intended semantics, but not compact so not strongly complete.

(Since completeness plus compactness gives strong completeness, you need a non-compact logic.)

Comment: Proof of non-compactness of PDL can be found [here](https://books.google.ca/books?id=izUG9d2iNosC&pg=PA175&lpg=PA175&dq=pdl+not+compact&source=bl&ots=j7XJA4Vhz3&sig=Xml5cjy8cNzqk6Eqk26EMQ5jVHM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjk_cuQwNbXAhUO5mMKHYtQBd8Q6AEIMzAC#v=onepage&q&f=false) (Theorem 5.10). Proof of "completeness + compactness gives strong completeness" follows easily from deduction theorem (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1771165/80673)).